# Strongswan IPSEC IKE with Docker Network Subnet

Tags: docker, ipsec, strongswan

I would like to setup strongswan on my DockerHost in order to allow containers on the leftSubnet which is a docker network subnet to communicate with my rightSubnet in the IPSEC TUNNEL.

10.0.10.0/24 which is my leftSubnet on DockerHost was created using:

```
docker network create --subnet 10.0.10.0/24
```

IPSEC IKE Configuration on DockerHost:

```
conn VPN-DOCKERHOST-REMOTE
    authby=secret               #this specifies how the connection is authenticated
    auto=start                  #start the connection by default
    type=tunnel                 #the type of connection
    left=1.1.1.1                #This is the public ip address of server MAESTRIA
    leftsubnet=10.0.10.0/24     #This is the subnet/private ip of server MAESTRIA
    right=2.2.2.2               #This is the public ip address of server RESAMUT/remote server
    rightsubnet=10.1.1.0/24     #This is the subnet/private ip of server RESAMUT
    ike=aes128-sha256-modp3072  #Internet key exchange, type of encryption keyexchange=ikev2 #Internet key exchange version
    ikelifetime=28800s          #Time before re authentication of keys
    esp=aes128-sha256           #Encapsulation security suite of protocols
```

IPSEC IKE is Up between my DockerHost and the RemoteServer, but I can't ping from my containers to the remote subnet.

I think trafics that match the remote subnet from my container are routed outside of the tunnel because of the iptables or something like that but I can't figure out the problem.